# Why does the Auto Copy Job function on AWS Redshift not suported?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift-serverless

I want to do continuous file ingestion from Amazon S3 to AWS Redshift, but the Auto Job copy doesn't work.

```
COPY "prueba 8" 
FROM 's3://xxxxxxxxxxxx'
IAM_ROLE  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
DATEFORMAT 'auto'
IGNOREHEADER 1
DELIMITER ','
IGNOREBLANKLINES 
REGION 'eu-west-1'
JOB CREATE job_sales AUTO ON;
```

If I don't use the las file y works but without doing the continues file ingestion.

The error is the next one:

```
ERROR: Auto copy job operation not supported
```

Comment: *If i dont use the las file y works* -- Please try to use clear language.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you read the advisory on this pre-release feature which is currently under development.  From the AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY-JOB.html):

> This is prerelease documentation for auto-copy (SQL COPY JOB), which
> is in preview release. The documentation and the feature are both
> subject to change. We recommend that you use this feature only in test
> environments, and not in production environments. Public preview will
> end on May 1, 2023. Preview clusters and preview serverless workgroups
> and namespaces will be removed automatically two weeks after the end
> of the preview. For preview terms and conditions, see Betas and
> Previews in AWS Service Terms.

Also, you need to create a "preview" cluster to have access to this feature - it isn't available on any Redshift cluster.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-copy-job.html for instructions on how to start a preview cluster.